# Show that run time complexity of operations on 2-4 tree is $O(\lg n)$

Tags: trees

I just studied about this 2-4 tree which is a self-balanced tree. Various sources and textbook often mentioned that the insertion, deleting and searching of this tree is $O(\lg n)$.

However, none of them explain the detailed reasons for that run-time complexity. Neither of them also explains them mathematically for the reason behind that run-time complexity.

Therefore, I would like to ask how do i basically show that the run time complexity to process a 2-4 with n keys is $O(\lg n)$?

Comment: The basic idea is that the depth of a 2-4 tree is $O(\log n)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tree is [height-balanced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), therefore the height of the tree is $O(\log n)$. So any insertion has to travel at most $O(\log n)$ steps deep into the tree to find the proper insertion place. Then it also takes another $O(\log n)$ steps the rebalance the tree. The same idea can be applied to searching and deleting in the tree.

The $O(\log n)$ height bound may be difficult to see in a 2-3-4 tree, so I will offer an alternative way to come to this realization. Any [2-3-4 tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%E2%80%933%E2%80%934_tree) is [*isometric*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry) to a proper [Red-Black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). That is to say, "they are equivalent data structures. In other words, for every 2–3–4 tree, there exists at least one red–black tree with data elements in the same order." A Red-Black tree is a balanced binary search tree whose height is more clearly bounded by $O(\log n)$ and so are all of its [operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Operations).

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. Never heard of the red-black tree before. Now there's another additional tree for me to know more about 2-4 trees.